# *Hardware* / Win 7 / External HDD + HUB / Correct shut down

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, shutdown, hub

I hope someone can answer me that question

Case:Im using several external HDD's which are connected to a hub, which again has it's own power supply and no on/off switch.

Problem: I don't want the HDD's to be powered all the time, although I want them to stay connected. They are normal external WD Elements 1-3TB.

I already tried googling for it but the terms just mess the results up.

Thanks a lot in advance ladies and gentlemen!

EDIT: and I do not want to go through "shut this disc down" via windows everytime, nor do I want to disconnect, as stated above.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand: The only way you can kill the power to these drives is to disconnect them, but you don't want to do that, nor shut them down from Windows. Doesn't this rule out all the options?

Comment: My 1 TB external WD Elements drive turns itself off (or at least goes into a low-power state with the discs powered-down) whenever it hasn't been used for a while. Don't recall the details, but whether it does this and, if enable, how long it waits were some kind of setup/installation option.

Comment: @Twisty Impersonator well i thought about something like setting, like stated below as answer, but just applied to the external hdd's I would select...maybe through a file which would be on the this, dunnow...

Comment: @martineau is it one of the small 2.5 or the big ones, the ones that come with an individual ac?

Comment: It's only a relatively small 4 TB external, but has its own separate AC power adapter. I misstated the size earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Windows should be able to shut these drives off when there not in use, after a certain amount of time.

To do this:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `powercfg.cpl`
2. Click 'Change Plan Settings'
3. Click 'Change Advanced Settings'
4. Change the timeout for drives to poweroff

[image: Powercfg.cpl]